# Adding co-author for a revised manuscript

Tags: publications, authorship, paper-submission

Is it possible to add a new co-author when requested for a second revision?

Another co-author would help improve the quality of the manuscript, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 10):

A revision to a manuscript is a chance to correct any issues raised in the original review. If you and your co-authors feel that adding a co-author would make the manuscript better, then it is of course acceptable to do so, absent **explicit** instructions to the contrary from the journal (although I am unaware of any journals with such rules).

However, you will also need to **clearly** explain in your cover letter to the editor why you added the co-author, and exactly what her contributions to the paper were.

Answer (score 7):

This is quite common. Authors take in an additional author to help sort out a specific problem and add that author to the paper. It is of course customary to provide a detailed account of this change as well as any other revisions made for the review.